# Ajax keypress event ( the working behind it)

Tags: ajax, algorithm, web-services, sorting

I had a very interesting question asked to me today . I had a certain time before implemented a project that implemented the AJAX keypress event . So basically what happens is each time a key is pressed in a search bar it is queried on the database and the result is displayed on a div . So I never bothered to learn how it was implemented till today . Since the web has no guarentee of a response , how does Ajax know how to display the result of the keypress in a sequence

for example

if I type a --> displays the result for a ,
now if I add a "b" making it ab  , it displays the result for ab

but since the web offers no guarantee , the response for ab may come before the response for a ( if a person typed the letters fast) .

Some possible explanations I thought of

1) storing the request with the result (but again a sort would be needed and will not be time or space inefficient) 
2) a timestamp ( but because there is no guarentee of the time , this could be totally misleading)

I am honestly not sure how it works and would like to know how this is implemented .

Thank you

Edit: I apologise if I framed the question wrong , I used javascript to send GET and POST requests to a servlet that interacted with a database

Comment: AJAX is a technique, not a library or function. To say that AJAX has events or "knows" how to do anything is wrong. Exactly how your project's functionality worked is dependent on whatever library you did use that implemented it, such as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to have the answer describe itself.
e.g. "the results for 'a' are apple, aarvark, avocado"

When if you get an answer where the base string mentioned doesn't match the current input string, you ignore it.  i.e. if you get the above after 'b' has been typed, it is quietly ignored.